# SSH troubles pushing with Git

Tags: git, ssh

I'm trying to set up a git repository on Assembla (assembla.com) and I'm having trouble making my first "push". I'm fairly ignorant of git, but I've previously successfully pushed to a repository on github. I'm using git on Windows Vista. When I run git bash from the relevant directory and type "git push", I get:

```
The authenticity of host 'git.assembla.com (64.250.188.42)' can't be established.
RSA fingerprint is 31:06:...(omitted)...:07:e6.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Entering "yes" is no good, it doesn't accept the passphrase.

I know that this has something to do with SSH keys, but I can't figure out what might be wrong with mine. My git name and email on my local machine match up with the ones I've entered on Assembla, and I've tried generating a new SSH key and uploading the id_rsa.pub file to Assembla to no effect.

A search turned up this forum thread: http://forum.assembla.com/forums/3/topics/2754

As far as I can tell none of the suggestions raised by the administrator in the final post apply. 1 and 2 shouldn't apply because this is a vanilla account on the site and I haven't changed any settings. 3, 4 and 5 I believe I have done. 6 I have done, although I deleted the line "GSSAPIAuthentication" because it generated an additional error message.

---

NB. I have another open question on StackOverflow regarding Git. This question is unrelated and concerns a different Windows machine. I have not abandoned my other question.

---

**Edit:**

Output of `ssh -v git@git.assembla.com`:

```
$ ssh -v git@git.assembla.com
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/Philip/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for git.assembla.com
debug1: Connecting to git.assembla.com [64.250.188.42] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Philip/.ssh/id_rsa.pub type 1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5-assembla
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5-assembla pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
The authenticity of host 'git.assembla.com (64.250.188.42)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 31:06:3b:0d:cd:23:1a:41:dc:f2:c5:7d:9c:24:07:e6.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Output of `git remote -v`:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@git.assembla.com:ksv.git (fetch)
origin  git@git.assembla.com:ksv.git (push)
```

The password prompt:

```
$ git push
The authenticity of host 'git.assembla.com (64.250.188.42)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 31:06:3b:0d:cd:23:1a:41:dc:f2:c5:7d:9c:24:07:e6.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'git.assembla.com,64.250.188.42' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Philip/.ssh/id_rsa.pub':
```

Comment: So after entering "yes" to accept the host key, then it asks for the password?  Or not?  Can you show us the complete output of your push attempt?  Does assembla use ssh keys or usernames/passwords, and if it uses keys have you either (a) loaded the key into an ssh-agent, or (b) configured ssh to use the correct key for your connections to assembla?

Comment: In particular, it would be useful to see the password prompt, so we can check whether it's the password to your private key that's being asked for, or it's for password authentication to assembla.  Also, the output of `ssh -v git@git.assembla.com` and `git remote -v` would be useful to see.

Comment: @Mark, I have added the output of those commands to the question, and the password prompt.

Comment: (The output from `ssh -v git@git.assembla.com` isn't complete - it's the bit after you say "yes" that's particularly of interest.)  One odd thing there, however, is that it's asking you for the password to your *public* key, `id_rsa.pub`, rather than you private key, which would just be `id_rsa`.  It should be doing the latter.  Have you put any configuration in `/c/Users/Philip/.ssh/config` by any chance?

Comment: I had entered some lines in `config`, as per the suggestion of the Assembla support person on the forum page linked in the question. Where the forum post indicated that I should put the name of my 'private key file', however, I mistakenly put the name of my public key file. Trying again, I get the error "No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing. Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'". I presume that this means that connection was successful, and I am running into an unrelated issue. Write a suitable answer (for the connection issue), and I will accept it.

Comment: I have now successfully pushed to assembla using `git push origin master`. As I said, if you write an answer explaining that the wron file was referenced in `config`, I will accept it.

Comment: @Hammerite: great, I'm glad to hear that's working for you now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks from the error message as if the problem is that you're specifying your *public* key (`id_dsa.pub`) as `IdentityFile` in your `.ssh/config` file instead of your *private* key, which would be just `id_dsa`.

The questioner has confirmed in the comments above that this was the problem.