# SSH the authenticity of [server] can't be established

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys, assembla

I have no control over the server and therefore cannot do what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663895/ssh-the-authenticity-of-host-hostname-cant-be-established) recommends. I've already followed what [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540234/ssh-troubles-pushing-with-git) pair already recommends.

My simple `ssh` attempt fails with "Host key verification failed":

```
$ ssh -v git@git.assembla.com
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/josvic/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to git.assembla.com [64.250.188.42] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/josvic/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/josvic/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/josvic/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/josvic/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/josvic/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/josvic/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5-assembla
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5-assembla pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA b7:7a:ad:9f:57:6f:ec:19:56:60:62:18:32:7a:8c:1b
The authenticity of host 'git.assembla.com (64.250.188.42)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is b7:7a:ad:9f:57:6f:ec:19:56:60:62:18:32:7a:8c:1b.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? 
Host key verification failed
```

Any idea?

Comment: you just need to type `yes` when you are asked to. Why don’t you do that?

Comment: @Chronial I assumed that by just hitting the ReturnKey it would be the same as typing in "yes"! Assumption is the mother of all... thanks! Pls enter your comment as answer and I will mark it as correct, as it came in before the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add server's key fingerprint to trusted keys file.
Just connect to that server with ssh client and type 'yes' when it will ask about the key.
Or, edit trusted_keys file manually.

Comment: Thanks, +1ed. If @Chronial puts his comment as answer I'll mark his answer as correct though as his comment came in before your answer.